# Stop submit button being pressed until enough words are written in text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically what I want is for the submit button to be disabled until a certain word count has been reached in the text area.

I have had a look around and tried to find ways to do it, with no luck.

Any tips or help?

```
<form method="post" id="writearticle" action="submitarticle.php">      
  <script>
    $('#writearticle').submit(function(event) {
        var text = $("#content").val();
        text = text.split(" ");
        // check for at least 10 words
        if(text.length < 10){
            console.log("prevented");
            // prevent submit
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        console.log("submitted");
    });
  </script>

  <textarea rows="30" cols="85" id="content" name="content" placeholder="Write the article here. Try to abide by the instructions and keywords provided."></textarea>
  <br />    
  <input type="submit" name="submitarticle" value="Submit Article" class="submit" />    
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Here is an example on how to count words: http://javascript.about.com/library/blcount.htm. Just add another script that disables submit, when you reach your desired limit.

Answer (score 1):

Show us your code.
1) Set `onclick` event for the submit button
2) [Check length in textarea](http://javascript.about.com/library/blcount.htm)
3) `return false` and `preventDefault()` if there is not enough words.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the word/charactor count in `keyup` event.

Answer (score 0):

see this example at http://elylucas.net/post/Enabling-a-submit-button-when-a-textbox-has-value-in-jQuery.aspx

instead of checking for a value, you split the input string in the text box and see the length of the array is more than your desired word count

Comment: then you can use a .change() function instead

Comment: `.change()` does not fire correctly for textarea. but it works well for select, checkbox etc.

Answer (score 0):

You catch the submit event, you count the words in the textarea and only submit if it is high enough. Example:

```
$('#targetForm').submit(function(event) {
    var text = $("#myTextarea").val();
    text = text.split(" ");
    // check for at least 10 words
    if(text.length < 10){
        // prevent submit
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xmmh3/1/)

Comment: Tried it, now it doesn't want to submit at all; no matter how many words. Edited what I've got so far into the OP.

Comment: The demo works, that shouldn't be the problem. Try to put the script tag outside of your form?

Answer (score 0):

Try out below lines of code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit-name").attr("disabled", "true");
    var minLength = 100;
    $("#your-text-area").bind('keyup', function(event) {
        var String = $("#your-text-area").val()

           if (String.length >= minLength )  {  
                $(".submit-name").removeAttr("disabled");
            } else {
                $(".submit-name").attr("disabled", "true");        
            }

});



});
```

Comment: obviously at the bottom of your HTML code. you just need to replace all the **classes** and **IDs** of this code with your original once.. :) let me inform if having any queries..

Answer (score 0):

Use the `textchange` (not built-in) event to accurately detect text changes via keyboard, paste etc. - http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

```
$('textarea').bind('textchange', function () {
   // $(this).val() contains the new text
});
```

In your text-change event, check the length/count the words in your text and enable disable the submit button as needed (make sure its initially disabled).