# Enabling submit button when word count is reached

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop submit button being pressed until enough words are written in text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527942/stop-submit-button-being-pressed-until-enough-words-are-written-in-text-area)

So basically I have the code below. I wish to enable the submit button when the word count in the text area reaches more than 5. The code below isn't working. Ideas?

```
<form method="post" id="writearticle" action="submitarticle.php"> 
    <textarea rows="30" cols="85" id="content" name="content" placeholder="Write the article here. Try to abide by the instructions and keywords provided." onkeydown="checkWordCount();" ></textarea> 
    <br />      
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submitarticle" value="Submit Article" class="submit" disabled />     

<script type="text/javascript">                         
    function checkWordCount() { 
    var wordCount = document.getElementById('content').value.split(" ").length;
    if (wordCount > 5) { 
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false; 
        } else { 
            document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true; alert("lol"); 
        } 
    }
    </script>
    </form>
```

Comment: Nothing I did there works mate.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, since the other question uses jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, the problem is the event that you're firing on. If you enter more than 5 words in the `textarea`, the `submit` button is enabled, but then if you highlight all of the text, and remove it, the `wordCount` remains the same, so the `submit` button isn't disabled.

Try changing `onkeydown` to `onkeyup`, that should fix the problem.

**edit**

In response to your comments, **check that the IDs of the elements you are using are unique**, if not, it will cause problems!

Comment: When you say it's not working - what exactly is not working? I tested your code locally and it worked fine - other than the problem I described in my answer.

Comment: The submit button remains disabled. :( it works when the form is on its own page with nothing else. But doesn't work when its within the real style and other code.. I'll upload the whole page code now.

Comment: Yes you were right. Fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
s = document.getElementById("content").value;
s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
len = s.split(' ').length;
```

Now pass the len value into your if condition.

Answer (score 0):

call function in onkeyup function of textarea- onkeyup="checkWordCount();"

And then use jQuery to check the count like this.

```
  function checkWordCount()
    {
      var lengthofText=$("#content").val().length;
        if (lengthofText> 5) { 
               document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false; 
            } else { 
               document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true; 
            } 

      }
```